# memberID not defined in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controllers

I am trying to update the details of a specific user and it keeps giving me the error that memberID is not defined in the script. What should I write instead? Already tried memb and still gave me the same error. Thanks for the help

```
Members.controller('editMembers',['$scope','$http','$routeParams',function($scope, $http,$routeParams){
    var id=$routeParams.id;
    console.log(id);
    $scope.updateMember="";

    //populating data with exsisting member details
    $http.post('PHP/getMemberByID.php',{'id':id}).success(function(data){
        $scope.memb=data;
        console.log(data);
    });

    $scope.updateMember = function(project) {
        $http.post('PHP/editMembers.php/'+id, memberID).success(function(data) {
            if (data) {//row updated
              console.log("Succesful Update");
            } else {
              console.log("Unsuccesful Update");
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Where you have defined memberID? is it coming in data from $http.post ?

Comment: where memberId is defined?

Comment: Just fixed the problem thanks both :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the memberID in the function in place of project

```
$scope.updateMember = function(memberID) {
    $http.post('PHP/editMembers.php/'+id, memberID).success(function(data) {
        if (data) {//row updated
            console.log("Succesful Update");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Unsuccesful Update");
        }
    });
};
```

or if the memberID is in the project collection then do like

```
$scope.updateMember = function(project) {
    $http.post('PHP/editMembers.php/'+id, project.memberID).success(function(data) {
        if (data) {//row updated
            console.log("Succesful Update");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Unsuccesful Update");
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Great thanks it worked! Haven't noticed by that stupid mistake I was doing. Still need it to be saved in phpmyadmin though....